# Assign multiple Static IP address to one NIC

Tags: server, 22.04, configuration, ip, static-ip

Please, I need help on to assign multiple static IP's with different on one NIC for 2 different IP like 192.168.xx.xx/24 and 172.16.xx.xx/24. Any idea of how to configure it on Ubuntu Server 22.04.

I tried creating the static ip in etc/netplan/00-install

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: 
      - 192.168.1.212/24 
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      routes:
      - to: default 
        via: 192.168.1.2
```

Comment: Your configuration doesn't show you setting both addresses.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Technically, it's easy to put two IP addresses on a single NIC, even if they are in different subnets: just add them to the addresses list. But you'll also need routing rules to that make sure that traffic leaving your system has the desired origin IP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nmcli` to assign the IP addresses.

**For multiple interfaces**

```
nmcli con add con-name static1 type ethernet ipv4.addresses <IP_ADDRESS>/<SUBNET_CIDR> ipv4.method manual ipv4.gateway <GATEWAY_IP> connection.autoconnect yes ifname <INTERFACE> ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4" 

route add -net <Network> netmask <subnet> dev <interface>
route add default gw <gateway>
```

Example with data filled...

```
nmcli con add con-name static1 type ethernet ipv4.addresses 192.168.0.101/24 ipv4.method manual ifname eth0 ipv4.gateway 192.168.0.1 ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4" connection.autoconnect yes

nmcli con add con-name static2 type ethernet ipv4.addresses 172.16.0.101/24 ipv4.method manual ifname eth1 ipv4.gateway 172.16.0.1 ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4" connection.autoconnect yes

route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1
route add default gw 192.168.0.1
route add -net 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
```

**For a single interface**

```
# For routes nmcli has a ipv4.routes option that is "<IP_NETWORK>/<CIDR> <GATEWAY>, <IP_NETWORK_2> <GATEWAY_2>,..."
nmcli con add con-name static2 type ethernet ipv4.addresses 172.16.0.101/24,192.168.0.101/24 ipv4.method manual ifname eth0 ipv4.gateway 172.16.0.1 ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4" connection.autoconnect yes

route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
route add default gw 192.168.0.1
route add -net 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
```

Documentation on some of the items shown:

**Using route for setting routes**
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/understand-the-basics-of-linux-routing/

**Basic nmcli documentation**
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_ip_networking_with_nmcli

**Related to using ipv4.routes with nmcli**

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_static_routes_using_nmcli

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/configuring-static-routes_configuring-and-managing-networking

Comment: Your answer assumes the machine has two NICs. The question is how to do this on _a single NIC_.

Comment: @zwets I can change my answer for a single interface.

Comment: Thanks let me give it a try

Comment: All this configuration can be done on the /etc/netplan ?

Comment: @jesushova this is done via command line. This will create essentially a network profile called "static2" in the single interface example. The configuration should be possible via /etc/netplan but I do not know how to configure that, only know how to configure via `nmcli`

Comment: Okay I will install network-manager and try it.

Comment: after installing Network Manager, i used the nmcli device show and it showed me all what is on and all that. I will go ahead and use your code and see if it work. Thank you once again